# How do I map a single file using ResourceHandlerRegistry and Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC app where I define a static resource haandler like this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    if (resourceIdentifier != null) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/admin-ui/**", "/admin-ui/").addResourceLocations(
                "file:" + resourceIdentifier.getResourcesLocation() + "/");
    }
}
```

(For brevity, I have elided the rest of the `HandlerInterceptor` declaration.)

Now, the main entry point of the app is:

```
https://foo.mysite.com/admin-ui/index.html
```

Instead, I want the entry point to be:

```
https://foo.mysite.com/admin-ui
```

Currently, this gives a 404 error. What is the easiest way to enable this, preferably using the `ResourceHandlerRegistry`?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot use `ResourceHandlerRegistry`. You need to map your path to a `@Controller` handler method and write the html file directly to the response body.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following controller, which works partially:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("admin-ui").setViewName("/admin-ui/index.html");
}
```

I needed to make a few other changes in my app since the other assets, e.g., the css, js, and template files were being accessed relative the index.html (i.e., with no `admin-ui/` as part of the path).  I needed to change this to being an absolute path to the server root, so for example in index.html:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

became this:

```
<link href="/admin-ui/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After doing this for all urls in the app, I can now access the app with or without the `index.html`.